# React useEffect dependancies

Tags: reactjs

I have app for booking. If user click to booking details btn, user can see data. Data are fetched, but useEffect is not happy.

useEffect shows me this err msg:
React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getDetails'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

I cannot remove the dependency array, it give infinitive loop, correct? So how to fix this?
I was trying put there almost everything what I have, but still got yellow underlined.

```
const BookedDetails = () => {

  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.userAuth)
  const userID = user?.user?._id

  const [details, setDetails] = React.useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [invoiceLoad, setInvoiceLoad] = React.useState(false)
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState(1)
  const [postPerPage, setPostPerPage] = React.useState(4)

  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postPerPage
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postPerPage
  const currenPosts = details.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost)

 const pages = []

 for(let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(details.length / postPerPage); i++) {
  pages.push(i)
 }

 const paginate = (x) => {
    setCurrentPage(x)
 }


  const getDetails = async () => {

    const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
      }

    try {
      setLoading(true)
      const res = await axios.post('/api/bookingDetails/bookDetails', { userID }, config )     
      //console.log(res.data.user)
      setDetails(res.data.user)
      setLoading(false)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getDetails()
  },[ ])    //  << dependency is yellow underlined.
```

Comment: Hi, do you need getDetails method in other parts of the component?

Comment: NO, it is just for this page.

Comment: I mean you need only one call in this component?

Comment: Yes only this call.

Comment: If the userID changes, the getDetails function will not be called again and the details state will not be updated. isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. please see the below answer. - @NirmalSankalana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `getDetails` method in `useEffect` hook.

For example:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const getDetails = async () => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.post(
        "/api/bookingDetails/bookDetails",
        { userID },
        config
      );

      setDetails(res.data.user);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  getDetails();
}, [userID]);
```

---

### Updated Answer

If you need to call `getDetails()` more than once, you can move the `getDetails()` function outside of the `useEffect` hook and use a `useCallback` hook to memoize it. Then you can pass it as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook and also call it from other places in your component.

For example:

```
const getDetails = React.useCallback(async () => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  try {
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await axios.post(
      "/api/bookingDetails/bookDetails",
      { userID },
      config
    );

    setDetails(res.data.user);
    setLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    setLoading(false);
  }
}, [userID, setLoading, setDetails]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  getDetails();
}, [getDetails]);
```

Comment: It shot me again yellow underlined, when I hover it, it show me, miising 'useID', I put there userID and it is working properly.   THANK YOU !!!

Comment: Hi Victor, If I need call getDetails() more than once, how can I fix this problem with dependency, Thanks